# Recognizing poker hands from a 2D matrix of values

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 1000 x 5 sorted matrix with numbers from 1-13.  Each number denotes the numerical value of a playing card.  The Ace has the value 1, then the numbers 2 through 10 follow, then the Jack has value 11, Queen with value 12 and King with value 13.  Therefore, each row of this matrix constitutes a poker hand.   I am trying to create a program that recognizes poker hands using these  cards that are enumerated in this way.

For example:

```
A =  [1 1 2 4 5;  2 3 4 5 7;  3, 3, 5, 5, 6; 8, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Therefore, in this matrix `A`, the first row has a pair (1,1). The second row has high card (7), the third row has two pair ((3,3) and (5,5)) and the last one is a full house (Pair of 9s and 3 of a kind (8).

Is there a good way to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Project Euler exercise?

Comment: `bsxfun` won't work for this.

Comment: Now as we know what you want, it would be interesting to know what you have done.

Comment: Don't you need all 52 cards so you can do things like flushes?

Answer (score 6):

`bsxfun` won't work for this situation.  This is a **counting problem**.  It's all a matter of counting what you have.  Specifically, poker hands deal with counting up how much of each card you have, and figuring out the right combination of counts to get a valid hand.  Here's a nice picture that shows us every possible poker hand known to man:

[image]

<sup>Source: http://www.bestonlinecasino.tips</sup>

Because we don't have the suits in your matrix, I'm going to ignore the Royal Flush, Straight Flush and the Flush scenario.  Every hand you want to recognize can be chalked up to taking a histogram of each row with bins from 1 to 13, and determining if (in order of rank):

- Situation #1: A high hand - all of the bins have a bin count of exactly 1
- Situation #2: A pair - you have exactly 1 bin that has a count of 2
- Situation #3: A two pair - you have exactly 2 bins that have a count of 2
- Situation #4: A three of a kind - you have exactly 1 bin that has a count of 3
- Situation #5: Straight - You don't need to compute the histogram here.  Simply sort your hand, and take neighbouring differences and make sure that the difference between successive values is 1.
- Situation #6: Full House - you have exactly 1 bin that has a count of 2 **and** you have exactly 1 bin that has a count of 3.
- Situation #7: Four of a kind - you have exactly 1 bin that has a count of 4.

---

As such, find the histogram of your hand using [`histc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) or [`histcounts`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histcounts.html) depending on your MATLAB version.  I would also pre-sort your hand over each row to make things simpler when finding a straight.  You mentioned in your post that the matrix is pre-sorted, but I'm going to assume the general case where it may not be sorted.

As such, here's some pre-processing code, given that your matrix is in `A`:

```
Asort = sort(A,2); %// Sort rowwise
diffSort = diff(Asort, 1, 2); %// Take row-wise differences
counts = histc(Asort, 1:13, 2); %// Count each row up
```

`diffSort` contains column-wise differences over each row and `counts` gives you a `N x 13` matrix where `N` are the total number of hands you're considering... so in your case, that's 1000.  For each row, it tells you how many of a particular card has been encountered.  So all you have to do now is go through each situation and see what you have.

Let's make an ID array where it's a vector that is the same size as the number of hands you have, and the ID tells you which hand we have played.  Specifically:

```
* ID = 1 --> High Hand
* ID = 2 --> One Pair
* ID = 3 --> Two Pairs
* ID = 4 --> Three of a Kind
* ID = 5 --> Straight
* ID = 6 --> Full House
* ID = 7 --> Four of a Kind
```

As such, here's what you'd do to check for each situation, and allocating `out` to contain our IDs:

```
%// To store IDs
out = zeros(size(A,1),1);

%// Variables for later
counts1 = sum(counts == 1, 2);
counts2 = sum(counts == 2, 2);
counts3 = sum(counts == 3, 2);
counts4 = sum(counts == 4, 2);

%// Situation 1 - High Hand
check = counts1 == 5;
out(check) = 1;

%// Situation 2 - One Pair
check = counts2 == 1;
out(check) = 2;

%// Situation 3 - Two Pair
check = counts2 == 2;
out(check) = 3;

%// Situation 4 - Three of a Kind
check = counts3 == 1;
out(check) = 4;

%// Situation 5 - Straight
check = all(diffSort == 1, 2);
out(check) = 5;

%// Situation 6 - Full House
check = counts2 == 1 & counts3 == 1;
out(check) = 6;

%// Situation 7 - Four of a Kind
check = counts4 == 1;
out(check) = 7;
```

---

Situation #1 basically checks to see if all of the bins that are encountered just contain 1 card.  If we check for all bins that just have 1 count and we sum all of them together, we should get 5 cards.

Situation #2 checks to see if we have only 1 bin that has 2 cards and there's only **one such bin**.

Situation #3 checks if we have 2 bins that contain 2 cards.

Situation #4 checks if we have only 1 bin that contains 3 cards.

Situation #5 checks if the neighbouring differences for each row of the sorted result are all equal to 1.  This means that the entire row consists of 1 when finding neighbouring distances.  Should this be the case, then we have a straight.  We use [`all`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) and check every row independently to see if all values are equal to 1.

Situation #6 checks to see if we have one bin that contains 2 cards **and** one bin that contains 3 cards.

Finally, Situation #7 checks to see if we have 1 bin that contains 4 cards.

---

A couple of things to note:

- A straight hand is also technically a high hand given our definition, but because the straight check happens later in the pipeline, any hands that were originally assigned a high hand get assigned to be a straight... so that's OK for us.
- In addition, a full house can also be a three of a kind because we're only considering the three of a kind that the full house contains.  However, the later check for the full house will also include checking for a pair of cards, and so any hands that were assigned a three of a kind will become full houses eventually.

---

One more thing I'd like to note is that if you have an invalid poker hand, it will automatically get assigned a value of 0.

---

Running through your example, this is what I get:

```
>> out

out =

     2
     1
     3
     6
```

This says that the first hand is a one pair, the next hand is a high card, the next pair is two pairs and the last hand is a full house.  As a bonus, we can actually output what the strings are for each hand:

```
str = {'Invalid Hand', 'High Card', 'One Pair', 'Two Pair', 'Three of a Kind', 'Straight', 'Full House', 'Four of a Kind'};
hands = str(out+1);
```

I've made a placeholder for the invalid hand, and if we got a legitimate hand in our vector, you simply have to add 1 to each index to access the right hand.  If we don't have a good hand, it'll show you an `Invalid Hand` string.

We get this for the strings:

```
hands = 

    'One Pair'    'High Card'    'Two Pair'    'Full House'
```

Comment: @Benoit_11 - LOL I know eh?

Comment: I know these kinds of comments are discouraged, but *wow*. Very nice answer dude.

Comment: @jucestain - Thanks a lot :).  I usually leave comments for really good answers too, and a lot of your image processing posts are very deserving of a wow comment!

Comment: Is it just me or is it interesting this is almost 2 years old and nobody has noticed the "one pair" example in the image has two Ace of Clubs depicted.